# copy_blob function fails when there is "En Dash" (–) in blob url

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, python-3.7

I need to copy a file with en dash "Depot – Week.xlsx"  to some other Blob Storage location(container).

`block_blob_service` is an object of the `BlockBlobService` class  (`azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice`)

code snippet below:

```
block_blob_service.copy_blob(archive_container, "pleasegodpleaseplease.xlsx",                                                         "https://dapblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/daps3blob/kuldeep/Depot – Week.xlsx")
```

I'm getting the following error -

> Client-Request-ID=9e183a7e-a24d-11e9-9423-f48e389d3b95 Retry policy did not allow for a retry: , HTTP status code=Unknown, Exception=latin-1.
>   Failed to archive files : latin-1

Comment: Have you tried using the url-encoded name of the file? `https://dapblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/daps3blob/kuldeep/Depot%20%E2%80%93%20Week.xlsx`

Comment: @Chillie It's working!! I'll look for a way to encode url now

Comment: @Chillie urllib.parse.quote converts ':' to '%3A'. Do you know a way to fix this :/

Comment: @Chillie...Please put your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just as summary for the comments and my additional content.

There is an offical document [`Naming and Referencing Containers, Blobs, and Metadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata) introduces what characters can not be used in container or blob name. To fix it, a common solution is to encode the name or url by UTF-8/URL Encoder.

In Python, the code is as below and to fix the issue for some special characters like `:` and `/` not need to be encoded by function [`urllib.parse.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) with the parameter `safe`.

[image]

```
# In Python 3.7
from urllib import parse
url_str = 'https://dapblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/daps3blob/kuldeep/Depot - Week.xlsx'
url_str_quoted = parse.quote(url_str, safe=':/')
print(url_str_quoted)
# The result is  https://dapblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/daps3blob/kuldeep/Depot%20-%20Week.xlsx

# for En Dash
print(parse.quote('Depot – Week.xlsx'))
# The result is Depot%20%E2%80%93%20Week.xlsx
```

Note: the dash (-) character can be used in the name of container and blob,

> Every dash (-) character must be immediately preceded and followed by
>   a letter or number; consecutive dashes are not permitted in container
>   names.

but the whitespace character can not be used in container name and must be encoded in blob name and its url.